# Signature input with jSignature to insert in Excel

Tags: php, excel, png, jsignature

I'm using jSignature to take on my web site the signature of a client in a form.
Then, when the submit button in a form is clicked, I get the signature in svg64 format and then I pass it with post to a php page.
Here all works, but now I have to convert the string that refers to the svg image into an image that I can put into an Excel file (also this automatically in php).

This is an example of the svg that I have to converter

```
image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

How can I do? Is possibile to obtain an Image that could be automatically saved in an Excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, I solved it using this

```
//Acquisizione dati dal form
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "$name";
$signature = $_POST['signature_value'];    
$data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '' , $signature);
$data = base64_decode($data);


$output_file="$name.png";
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
  if ($im !== false) {
      imagealphablending($im, false);
      imagesavealpha($im, true);
      //header('Content-Type: image/png'); è superfluo, siccome l'immagine non viene mostrata qua
      imagepng($im, $output_file );
      //imagepng($im);
      imagedestroy($im);
  }
  else {
      echo 'An error occurred.';
  }
```